# Mocked function doesn't return value class correctly in Scala

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest, value-class, mockito-scala

I need to mock a function from an arbitrary type to another type that is a [value-class](/questions/tagged/value-class).
For example with the following signature `String => ValueClass`.
This is how my [value-class](/questions/tagged/value-class) is implemented:

```
final case class ValueClass(value: String) extends AnyVal
```

I am using [mockito-scala](/questions/tagged/mockito-scala) to mock and [scalatest](/questions/tagged/scalatest) to matche result:

```
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, MockitoSugar}
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpecLike}

class ValueClassMockTest 
   extends WordSpecLike
    with MockitoSugar
    with ArgumentMatchersSugar
    with Matchers {

  "mocked function" should {
    "return the same value class" in {
      val f: String => ValueClass = mock[String => ValueClass]

      when(f(any[String])).thenReturn(ValueClass("str"))

      f("anyStringValue") shouldEqual ValueClass("str")
    }
  }

}
```

I wondering, why this test doesn't pass and mocked function returns unwrapped value?

```
"str" did not equal ValueClass(str)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: services.ValueClassMockTest at (ValueClassMockTest.scala:16)
Expected :ValueClass(str)
Actual   :"str"
<Click to see difference>
```

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion       = "2.12.10"
scalaTest          = "3.0.8"
mockitoScala       = "1.5.17"
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, would you mind raising an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I am opening an issue for it.

Comment: This may be tricky as Scala tries to return the unboxed value as much as possible and the presence of the compile-time type makes all the difference. Any reflection introduced by ScalaTest and Mockito could throw that off. Interesting problem.

Comment: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/issues/150

Comment: This seems to be related to an earlier issue (fixed in mockito-scala 1.0.3): https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/issues/61 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070901/mocking-a-method-which-returns-an-fs2-stream

Comment: Fixed! (see the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in v1.5.18 (https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/pull/152)

The issue comes from the fact that on a parametrised return type there is no type info in runtime, hence the value class is always boxed, I added extra provisions for those scenarios so the boxed instance is returned.

That said, for stuff like functions I think is a better idea to skip mocking altogether, unless the function is impure or you want to assert some unorthodox behaviour.